# How to create mint function but with msg.sender

Tags: solidity, web3js, erc-20

I want a mint function but instead of _mint(to, amount) i want _mint(msg.sender, amount) how can i do it??

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand correctly, but can you just write the function like this: `function _mint(uint amount) public { _mint(msg.sender, amount; }`, or so

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this:

```
function mint(uint256 _amount) public {

//Now you call the internal mint function from your ERC20 token
//You can find more about it here
//https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol

_mint(msg.sender, _amount);

}
```